# Изменить данные БД и другие при развертывании приложения на сервере [Spring Boot]

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

**Свое приложение на сервер я кидаю в виде Jar-файла!**

В моем приложении данные подключения к БД и путь к статичным файлам настроены под мой компьютер, но мне бы хотелось, чтобы я не заморачивался комментировать постоянно данные в `application.properties`, а просто программа сама понимала где она находится (на сервере или на компьютере) и сама брала нужные данные.

К примеру, для автонахождения маршрута к статичным файлам я использую следующую конфигурацию:

```java
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        if (new File("/path/on/my/computer/file/").isDirectory()) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/data/**").addResourceLocations(
                   "file:/path/on/my/computer/file/"
            );
        }

        if (new File("/path/on/my/server/files/").isDirectory()) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/data/**").addResourceLocations(
                    "file:/path/on/my/server/files/"
            );
        }

// некоторый код...

}
```

Данное решения я не считаю самым лучшим и считаю костылем. И мне бы хотелось от него избавиться.

Другой пример - это подключение к БД. Я вынес данные в отдельный файл `database.properties`. Я ДУМАЮ, что тут стоит вынести данный файл ВНЕ проекта и прописать к нему маршрут.

На данный момент мои данные к БД выглядят вот так:

```
# ==============================================================
# = Data Source
# ==============================================================

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database
spring.datasource.username=userRemote
spring.datasource.password=password1

#spring.datasource.username=userLocal
#spring.datasource.password=password2
```

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, вам нужны профили. Они позволяют создавать разные сборки, берущие данные из разных `*.properties` файлов. Это можно ещё улучшить через `Cloud Config`, но, думаю, это будет уже излишним.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб что-то в этом роде...! Если бы вы могли подсказать  ресурсы или кодом - было бы не плохо. Хочу хотя бы понять куда копать надо

Comment: С кодом сложно помочь. По идее достаточно копирнуть файл с конфигом и обозвать его с указанием профиля. Например `application.properties` и `application-dev.properties`. После этого надо указать нужный профиль. Я не знаю как это для `jar` сделать, но можете попробовать вот так: `java -jar application.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном ответе используется:
- идея [ЮрийСПб♦](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/%d0%ae%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b9%d0%a1%d0%9f%d0%b1)
- ответы на [данный вопрос с SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39738901/8992586)

На мой взгляд самый легкий способ - это создать несколько `application-[profile].properties`.

Для данного проекта я бы сделал бы **2 профиля**:

> 1. `prod` - данные, которые будут использоваться при развертывании приложения на сервере
> 2. `dev` - данные, которые будут использоваться при разработке приложения

В Spring-приложении в папке `resources` создаем три файла:

> - `application.properties`
> - `application-dev.properties`
> - `application-prod.properties`

#### application.properties:

Здесь будут записываться общие данные для профиля `prod` и для `dev`. Основываясь на данных вопроса, данные таблицы можно записать вот так:

```
# Некоторый код...

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database

# Некоторый код...
```

Так же в данном файле **выставим профиль по умолчанию:**

#### application-dev:

Здесь будут записываться данные, которые нам нужны при разработке приложения. К примеру:

```
spring.datasource.username=userLocal
spring.datasource.password=password1
path.static.resources=/path/on/my/computer/file/
```

#### application-prod:

Здесь будут записываться данные, которые нам нужны при развертывании приложения на сервере. К примеру:

```
spring.datasource.username=userRemote
spring.datasource.password=password1
path.static.resources=/path/on/my/server/files/
```

В итоге данный код:

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        if (new File("/path/on/my/computer/file/").isDirectory()) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/data/**").addResourceLocations(
                   "file:/path/on/my/computer/file/"
            );
        }

        if (new File("/path/on/my/server/files/").isDirectory()) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/data/**").addResourceLocations(
                    "file:/path/on/my/server/files/"
            );
        }

// некоторый код...

}
```

... можно сократить до одного метода и это уже перестанет выглядеть "костылем":

```java
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        @Value("${path.static.resource}")
        private String pathStatic;

        registry.addResourceHandler("/data/**").addResourceLocations(
            "file:" + pathStatic
        );

// некоторый код...

}
```

#### Переключение между профилями при развертывании приложения на сервере из jar-файла

Для выбора профиля используется `-Dspring.profiles.active=[profile]`. Данная строка заменяет `профиль по умолчанию` на нужный нам профиль

Так, к примеру, для установки профиля `prod` мы пишем следующее:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=prod ProjectName.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно на уровне сборщика брать application.properties из разных папок при сборке, но тогда надо постоянно вести два application.properties, которые мало чем отличаются.

Или можете использовать аннотацию `@Profile("dev")`. Подробно про использование профилей можно прочитать здесь https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles